# Handling IOExceptions

Tags: java, exception

Assuming there is a method getValueFormFile and it is pubic and returns an int. It accepts no arguments and is capable of throwing an IOException and a FIleNotFoundException.

Write a try statement that calls the getValueFormatFile method described above. Be sure to handle all the exceptions that the method can throw,

This is what I have

```
try {
  int value = getValueFromFile();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

Is this the proper way to handle the question?

Comment: You're not really *handling* exceptions when you have empty catch blocks.

Comment: Well, you could also just go with `catch(Exception e) { /* do nothing lol */ }`...

Comment: This sounds like you are using Stack Overflow to do your homework. I would recommend reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) on try/catch blocks first. There is a lot of information to help you on the web. Stack Overflow is not here to do the work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425281/java-style-properly-handling-exceptions?rq=1

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, ignoring exceptions is almost never the proper way to handle them.

You have to determine what handling the exception means in this case. Do you want to use a default value? Do you want to abort execution? Do you want to try a different method to obtain a value? Does selection of the correct strategy depend on whether the file is missing or whether it could not be read for some other reason?

Exceptions are thrown for the caller to handle precisely because correct handling depends on context which is known only to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You generally want to print the stack trace, log an error, or (usually not a good idea) populate the value with a default.

```
int value;
try {
  value = getValueFromFile();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    value = -1; // careful with this. Using -1 as an example because that's a common convention for representing an error condition
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    value = -1; // careful with this. Using -1 as an example because that's a common convention for representing an error condition
}
```

Comment: Gotcha.  That suggestion was optional as noted.  There are definitely situations where it is warranted, and I wanted to provide a moderately generalized answer.

Comment: What does the printStackTrace() method do?

Comment: IMO what you mostly want is to rethrow the checked exception as unchecked and not even try to recover from something like IOException.

Comment: printStackTrace() will output the [Java Stack Trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) to stdout.

Comment: So for this question was I right just that the catch's were not populated with anything?

Comment: I don't think that is the way to go.  You definitely want to log the error and/or print the stack trace so that the problem can be debugged more easily (these are void operations and won't affect the running of the program).